# existence of a complete manifold with certain assumptions

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose $(M,g)$ is a simply connected, complete Riemannian $N$-manifold with negative curvature, with its Ricci curvature bounded from below and for all $x\in M$ we have $\text{Vol}_g(B_1(x))\geq v$ for some $v>0$. ($B_1(x)$ being the unit geodesic ball with center at $x\in M$)

My question is, whether such a manifold could exist. And if it exists, can we construct such a manifold suitably? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't the Poincare upper half-plane (or Poincare disk) work? It has constant curvature (hence Ricci curvature) $-1$ and is simply connected. All the balls with radii 1 are isometric, since the space is homogeneous, so their volumes are equal to a constant.

The volume can be computed to be $4\pi\sinh^2\frac{1}{2}$, which corresponds to that on the sphere $S^2$, a geodesic ball of radius 1 has volume $4\pi\sin^2\frac 1 2$.

Comment: Right. I will also add the volume now.

Comment: Let’s call it area, since we’re in dimension $2$.

Comment: Do you call the geodesic balls geodesic disks too? Maybe it doesn't sound so bad.

Comment: Ball and disk both are used in $n$ dimensions :)

Comment: More generally, will the Cartan-Hadamard manifolds also work? I think in this case we only need to check the uniform lower bound for the balls.

Comment: My feeling is that the more negative the Ricci curvature (even scalar curvature?) is, the bigger the volume of the geodesic balls. So for a Cartan-Hadamard manifold, $K\leq 0$, $Ric\leq 0$, then the volume should be bigger than the Euclidean volume at least.

Comment: @Threeaggies I think that's true for Cartan-Hadamard manifolds, but the simply-connected assumption is crucial. Hyperbolic cusps are counter-example if one removes that assumption: unit geodesic balls have smaller and smaller volume (converging to $0$) when the centre is sent to infinity. (the heuristic "the more the scalar curvature is negative, the bigger is the volume of geodesic balls" is unfortunately true only infinitesimally in full generality)

Comment: @Didier Thanks, that helps explain many things.